# Android is it possible to load a jar without dx?

Tags: java, android, classloader

I'm trying to make a plugin system for my cross platform app.

I knew there's a DexClassLoader to load classes from a jar file.

But it requires to run a dx command, I want people can just load a jar file easily without using the dx command.

Is it possible? example: convert a jar file to dex at runtime or a jar classloader for android

Answer (score 0):

> convert a jar file to dex at runtime

Android does not offer this.

> a jar classloader for android

Android does not offer this either.

Also, bear in mind that using `DexClassLoader` may limit your app distribution options.

Comment: Is there any good way to make a plugin system?
I was stuck with this problem for a few days

Comment: @SonMooSans: If you want to distribute the app and plugins through places like the Play Store, the plugins would be apps, and the main app and the plugins would communicate through IPC mechanisms (starting activities, starting services, binding to services, sending targeted broadcasts, etc.).